# MySQL multiple updates - rollback if one fails

Tags: mysql, transactions

I need to update multiple rows in multiple tables and in case one of the updates fails, I want to undo all the changes done so far. How can I achieve that? Is a transaction enough?

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE TABLE1;
UPDATE TABLE2;
UPDATE TABLE3;

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do a rollback on error instead of a commit, e.g. with a handler

```
DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE table1;
UPDATE table2;
UPDATE table3;
IF `_rollback` THEN
    ROLLBACK;
ELSE
    COMMIT;
END IF;
```